# command not found when using sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo

There are a few question on the site that seem related to my problem but I could not find a solution in any of them.

My operating system is Ubuntu 12.04. I have `mvn` installed in `/tools/noarch/apache-maven-3.1.1` and I have added the following lines at the end of my `/etc/profile`:

```
export M2_HOME=/tools/noarch/apache-maven-3.1.1
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After that I execute `source /etc/profile`.

Now my problem is: when I run `mvn --version` the command succeeds and `mvn` executable is found, while if I execute: `sudo mvn --version` I get the output: `sudo: mvn: command not found`. I know that `PATH` may be different when I execute a command with `sudo` and that is why I tried this:

```
$>sudo echo $PATH
/tools/noarch/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:... some other stuff ...
```

Another thing I tried is to execute `sudo su -` and then type `mvn --version`. In this case `mvn` is successfully found and the command succeeds. What is going on here?

Comment: Related: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix SE

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`$PATH` is evaluated by your shell, so your check doesn't work as you expect it to.

`/etc/sudoers` is configured to replace your `PATH` with a default one.

`sudo` does not load a login shell environment before executing the command, so the default `PATH` from `/etc/sudoers` is used. `su -` does open a login shell, which involves loading `/etc/profile`. See `man bash`, section *INVOCATION*.

Just remove the `PATH` reset in `/etc/sudoers`. It's likely a rule called `secure_path`.

---

#### CentOS

In CentOS you can add `PATH` to the `Defaults env_keep` section:

```
Defaults    env_keep = "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR \
                        LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME \
                        LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION \
                        LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC \
                        LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS \
                        _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does solve the problem, but I prefer the solution suggestion in the other two answers as it performs a change only for maven, not for all commands in my PATH.

Comment: FYI: Please note my answer update.

Comment: how to sudo execute binaries in current directory `sudo: ./<some_binary>: command not found`. I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 52):

Give `sudo` your current `PATH` with:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" your_command
```

Comment: A great answer, which does not require modifying any settings, letting the caller do everything which is necessary. I would use the `-E` option in addition, to preserve the rest of the environment. In fact, this is so handy it can be put in a script/alias/function for easy use. I'll add this as a separate answer - but kudos to @opyate!

Comment: When I try to run this command I get `env: cmd: No such file or directory` - Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: @Andy replace cmd with your actual command.

Comment: how to sudo execute binaries in current directory `sudo: ./<some_binary>: command not found`. I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 15):

Elaborating on @opyate's answer, I am using the following shell script (which may be named `mysudo`, for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" "$@"
```

- `-E` tells `sudo` to preserve the environment.
- `env "PATH=$PATH"` is expanded outside the `sudo` call, making the external `PATH` available inside the `sudo` too (this is required in addition to the `-E` as the `PATH` usually receives special treatment in addition to the treatment the entire environment receives).
- `"$@"` passes the arguments our script receives to the `sudo` line.

Save the script in a file in a directory in the `PATH`, give it `+x` permissions, et voilà.

Comment: This is a much better solution for those that don't want to edit any existing files.

Answer (score 4):

Since the current answers are a little vague, the specific setting in `/etc/sudoers` changing your path is `secure_path`:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You can modify it it with `sudo visudo`, or better yet, add the directories you need:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I first installed [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). The problem got solved after I added the two lines,

```
export M2_HOME=/tools/noarch/apache-maven-3.1.1
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to four files:

```
/root/.bashrc
/root/.profile
```

and for the current user (`mehran` is my Ubuntu username):

```
/home/mehran/.bashrc
/home/mehran/.profile
```

Answer (score 1):

You must modify root's PATH variable exactly like you did for yourself, *i.e.* by adding those two lines in sudo's profile, which is located in /root/.bashrc, then source it.

Comment: I have edited /root/.bashrc but am not able to source it: `sudo source  /root/.bashrc` gets: `sudo: source: command not found` and without the `sudo` I get permission denied(as expected). i believe starting a new terminal should in theory do the same as source, but after starting a new terminal, `sudo mvn --version` still does not find anything.

Comment: @izomorphius You cannot sudo source. You must first switch to sudo with the command *sudo su*, then you can source the file in question. There is no other way to do it.