# Broken sudo commands

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, sudo, bashrc

How to *repair* `sudo` to use standard commands?

[image: Broken sudo]

I cannot use any command with `sudo`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/709515/command-not-found-when-using-sudo

Comment: This is about specific command, not all system default.

Comment: What’s the result of `sudo -s 'echo $PATH'` ?

Comment: `/bin/bash: echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory`