# linux command not found but whereis shows it is installed

Tags: linux

pip3.7 is installed and I can see its location using `whereis`. However centos says command not found. I don't understand why `command not found`. And I don't understand why later it is found.

[image]

Comment: So `pip3.7` works on it's own, but not with sudo? If it's not a quoting thing (try with double / single quotes around pip3.7) then maybe sudo's not set up to allow that command... or sudo's path is different

Comment: There's also no reason to use `sudo` in this example when you're already logged in as root.

Comment: I know no need to use sudo when logged in as a root. What I don't understand is `why command not found, and why command found`. >_<

Comment: Because sudo doesn't evaluate the same $PATH as root. Related: https://superuser.com/questions/709515/command-not-found-when-using-sudo

Comment: @n8te how to see the difference, the $PATH for sudo; and the $PATH for ordinary